# Simple phonebook lookup else function running even when if statement is true

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key-value

I'm trying to make a simple phone book where if you put type in
1: you add a contact to a dictionary, if
2 you lookup the dictionary based on the inputted name (key) if
3 you lookup the dictionary based on the inputted number (value)

When I run a key lookup based on value (input 3) it returns the else function 'this is invalid' regardless of whether or not it is true.

Can someone decipher this?

```
    #Input contact name
    if button == 1:
        name = input('Please enter the contact name:') 
        if name in contacts:
            print("The name you entered already exists in the address book --> %s:%s"\
            %(name,contacts[name]))
            flag = input("Whether to modify user information (YES/NO):")
            if  flag== 'YES':  
                tel = input('Please enter the users contact phone number:') 
                contacts.update({name:tel}) #Update dictionary
                print("Contacts have been updated!")
            else:
                continue
        else:
            contacts[name] =  input('Please enter the contact phone number:')
            print("Contact has been saved!")
    
    #Search by contact name
    if button == 2:
        name = input('Please enter the contact name:') 
        if name in contacts:
            print("%s : %s "%(name,contacts[name]))
        else:
            print('The name you entered is no longer in the address book! ') 
   
            
   #Search by contact number
    if button == 3:
        numba = input('Please enter the contact number:') 
        lookup = []
        for key,value in contacts.items():
            if(value == numba):
                lookup.append(key)
                print('Name(s) matching number is',lookup)
            else:
                print('This is invalid')
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) Is `if value == numba: ... else: ` the correct place to print "This is invalid"? `numba` is a string. Is `value` also a string?

Comment: The if clause is true once, when the correct value is found. But it is false for all the other iteration steps in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if button == 3:
    numba = input('Please enter the contact number:') 
    lookup = []
    for key,value in contacts.items():
        if(value == numba):
            lookup.append(key)
    if lookup: # True if len(lookup) != 0
        print('Name(s) matching number is', lookup)
    else:
        print('This is invalid')
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit of a stretch, but I made it work like this:

```
numba = input('Please enter the contact number: ')
lookup = []
for key,value in contacts.items():
    if(numba == key):
        lookup.append(value)
        print('Name(s) matching number is', lookup)

if(int(numba) > len(contacts.items())):
    print('This is invalid')
```